# Unable to write chart images in jsp page when Converting Struts Application into War file

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jfreechart

I've been using `JFree` Charts to display pie charts and bar charts in my Struts2 application. And I'm trying to print charts dynamically in JSP page with the help of SQL Queries.

In Eclipse charts are working fine. I'm getting updated data in charts with the help of SQL Queries. Then I'm converting Struts2 application into a war file.

But the charts are not getting updated, which means I am not able to write charts. I am confused why it's not working for *.war file, while it's working fine in Eclipse.

Comment: How are you making war file of your project ?

Comment: hi himanshu, from eclipse only i am creating a war file by export-war file option.

Comment: you need to build your application by ant or some other build tool, if you will directly create the war file from eclipse, it will not take all dependencies(jar files) and war file will not work as expected, check your logs may be you are getting some exceptions also related to jar files

Comment: thanx for reply@himanshu but is there any other solution??Bcz i am not using any build tool right now.

Comment: explode that war file and check what all jar files are there in that, if war file are missing, then let me know which server you are using?

Comment: i am using weblogic server.and using four jsp pages to print four charts.

Comment: try to keep missing jar files in your domain root lib and restart weblogic, check for conflict also, is there any conflict going on with weblogic jars and jars you are using?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: hi Roman C i have used some jfree charts lib,i am getting values from data base and setting value to object of DefaultPieDataset class, dataset1.setValue(rs.getString(1), rs.getInt(2));  JFreeChart chart1=ChartFactory.createPieChart("Total Sales(Daily)", dataset1, false, true, false);                                  then setting values to a png image, ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File(absoluteDiskPath,"chart.png"), chart1, 700, 400);

Answer (score 0):

I Got The Solution, it was actually **Weblogic Server** Problem,Just Use it         **Weblogic** admin console ->Domain->Web Applications - click the checkbox "Archived Real Path Enabled",Then Restart Server.it works for me.